Block Web Audio API in JS
I have problem with this notification when I play my game HTML5 made with construct 3 in android browser . When the game starts, the sounds play in the background even when I exit the browser. I tried this code :
  //
GoToLayout(layout) {
    if (this._runtime.IsLoading()) return;
    const layoutManager = this._runtime.GetLayoutManager();
    if (layoutManager.IsPendingChangeMainLayout()) return;
    
    // Audio notification blocking script
    (function() {
        // Store the original AudioContext
        const OriginalAudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        
        // Override AudioContext to add custom behavior
        window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext = function(...args) {
            const audioContext = new OriginalAudioContext(...args);
            
            // Override the close method
            const originalClose = audioContext.close;
            audioContext.close = function() {
                originalClose.call(this);
                // Additional cleanup to ensure no background audio
                this.destination.disconnect();
            };
            
            // Add an event listener for visibility change
            document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
                if (document.hidden) {
                    audioContext.suspend();
                } else {
                    audioContext.resume();
                }
            });
            
            return audioContext;
        };
        
        // Attempt to disable notifications
        if ('Notification' in window) {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
                if (permission === 'granted') {
                    // Override the Notification constructor to block audio notifications
                    const OriginalNotification = window.Notification;
                    window.Notification = function(title, options) {
                        if (options && options.silent === undefined) {
                            options.silent = true;
                        }
                        return new OriginalNotification(title, options);
                    };
                    window.Notification.requestPermission = OriginalNotification.requestPermission;
                }
            });
        }
    })();
    
    // Proceed with changing the layout
    layoutManager.ChangeMainLayout(layout);
},


But it doesn't work. I want a way to prevent this notification from appearing.
